# Unable to play Scorm 1.2 compliant content on Oracle Learning Management System (ebs 12.2)

Tags: oracle, scorm, lms

Message shown while playing SCORM content:

Error : **Unable to acquire LMS API.**

I try to access the same SCORM package on other LMS i.e. Moodle and it works fine. We can also observe that the same content is opened on our LMS after working hour.

On modern browsers it shows the same message, but it works after refreshing the page.

Comment: Does it run correctly in SCORM Cloud?

Comment: Yes it works there

Comment: then Oracle has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason behind this problem is a configuration error that locates the address actual SCORM java applet location.